# Iframe code not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I'm trying to make my iframe to auto login.

Here is my code. It's not logging in automatically. Whats the problem with my code?

```
<form id="login" target="frame" method="post" action="https://172.16.8.187:6060/NCMContainer.cc">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="user" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="pass" />
</form>
<iframe id="frame" name="frame"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // submit the form into iframe for login into remote site
    document.getElementById('login').submit();
    // once you're logged in, change the source url (if needed)
    var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
    iframe.onload = function() {
        if (iframe.src != "https://172.16.8.187:6060/NCMContainer.cc") {
            iframe.src = "https://172.16.8.187:6060/NCMContainer.cc";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Gserg thank you for editing please help

Comment: `submit the form into iframe for login into remote site` - yeah, your code isn't doing that at all - an iframe is loaded using the GET method - the login needs a POST method - you need to inject the form into the iframe, then fire the submit in the form in the iframe

Comment: can you please give me a guide code for that? i'm just a beginner i'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /><meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Numpty</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="frame.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

then create a new file, `frame.html`, which can look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /><meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="login" method="post" action="https://172.16.8.187:6060/NCMContainer.cc">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="user" />
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="pass" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('login').submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the iframe will be logged in to `https://172.16.8.187:6060/`

Comment: it's going to the page but it's not logging in. is there something missing? the field of username and password in the site is still blank.

Comment: check your developer tools console or network tabs - is the POST to `https://172.16.8.187:6060/NCMContainer.cc` happening? if not, there's a problem with my code, if so, then it's probably because `https://172.16.8.187:6060/NCMContainer.cc` doesn't like having a form submitted from whatever host your main.html is on